# Generate recurring events in fullcalendar from a fixed timeslots list

Tags: php, jquery, database-design, fullcalendar, recurring-events

I have a list of doctors and patients, whom have fixed schedules during several months (long treatments) as you can see in the image:

[image: Patient list with fixed schedules]

*So Clarice will have an appointment with Dr. Fenwick every Monday from 09:00 to 10:00 until the schedule is deleted*

I'm saving that info to the table as:

- id (int)
- day (1,2,3,4,5) where Monday=1, Tuesday=2...
- fk_doctor
- fk_patient
- start (time)
- end (time)

A) **How should I generate a list of recurrent events from that table, so I can fill a jQuery fullcalendar component?**

B) **How much better (or optimal) would be to save the entire list of repeating recurrent events into the table?**

The only advantages I see in B) would be the possibility to save a comment to each event, easy to load in fullcalendar, but I'd have lots of records and speed or loading time would be very affected because the data I showed is only 0.00001% of the real situation

Thanks for any idea/opinion you can suggest

Comment: What is a recurrent repeating event?

Comment: I can help you recently I have implemented same and it is in asp.net. Let me know are you coding in asp.net

Comment: @philipxy sorry for my english. i meant recurring event, an event that repeats its frequency, generally once, weekly.

Comment: @ramby sorry, i'm trying to build it with php+jquery, but i'm open to ideas which i could translate into php

Answer (score 1):

As my comment is too long so I am adding my comment as an answer.

ok, While adding the recurring events you should have following inputs on
the "Add Recurring Events" -

```
1) Occurence Type - Daily, Weekly, Month (as radiobuttons)
2) Recurring Days - Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun (as checkboxes)
3) Start Date and End Date
4) From Time and To Time
```

Now, If you select "Daily" option the "Recurring Days" and "End Date" should be
hidden/disabled.

If you select "Weekly" All 3 should be enabled.
here you need to calculate all dates between StartDate and EndDate as per the
selected days from "Recurring Days" checkboxes
eg. you selected

```
Occurence Type - Weekly
Recurring Days - Mon,  Wed
Start Date - 6-July-2014
End Date - 20-July-2014
```

Write a js function as

```
GetWeeklyDates(startdate, enddate)
{
// sorry no time write by urself, I had done this at asp.net end
}
```

your GetWeeklyDates function should return you following Dates:-
7-July-2014,9-July-2014,14-July-2014,16-July-2014

So now it becomes simple, just append From Time and End Time to each date and

run a loop at php end to add the events on these dates.

**you can also perform these algorithm at my sql end**

just pass start datetime and end datetime to the procedure

write a function in my sql to get Weekly Dates/ Monthly Dates

and loop the insert appointment statement

HOPE it helps you.